# Find the fundamental group of $\Bbb C^2 \setminus \{(x,y):xy=0 \}$.

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

What is the fundamental group of $\Bbb C^2 \setminus \{(x,y):xy=0 \}$?

How do I proceed? Please help me in this regard.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Hint: $xy=0$ is equivalent to $x=0$ or $y=0$. Both describe real hyperplanes in $\mathbb R^4\cong\mathbb C^2$.

Comment: Yeah that is correct. How do I somehow invoke here the concept of deformation retract or homotopy equivalence? Can I use Van Kampen's theorem?

Comment: Actually that is same as saying what is the fundamental group of $\Bbb R^4$ without two intersecting hyperplanes which sounds much like $\Bbb R^3$ without two intersecting planes upon taking projection. Right?

Comment: The description of the set you study is ambiguous: what are $x,y$ ? Complex  or real numbers?

Comment: I have found it from an online source. This is not the question which I made myself.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg : I believe OP means $ x,y $ are complex numbers. I answered the question in that case.

Comment: @hellHound: Yeah, that's what I thought too. But I wanted the OP's  confirmation before criticizing Christoph and stating that his comment is false (which it is!) :-)

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Erm right, $x=0$ in $\mathbb C^2$ is gives a $2$-dimensional plane in $\mathbb R^4$, not a hyperplane. Sorry for that. So these are two $2$-planes intersecting in a point.

Answer (score 9):

Your space $X$ is **exactly** equal to  $\mathbb C^\ast \times \mathbb C ^\ast$ so that $$\pi_1(X)= \pi_1(\mathbb C^\ast \times \mathbb C ^\ast)=\pi_1(\mathbb C^\ast )\times \pi_1(\mathbb C^\ast )=\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z$$

Comment: Much simpler, upvoted. Maybe I was drawn into $ \mathbb{R}^4 $ by the first comment.

Comment: Dear @hellHound: congratulations for your sense of fair-play, which is more valuable in my eyes than any mathematical calculation!

Comment: Dear @GeorgesElencwajg, sincere thanks for your kind words. As a student, the learning experience I take from your solution is to always think of the simplest concepts first while tackling any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sketch, but almost a complete solution: First observe that topologically, the space is $ \mathbb{R}^4 \setminus (H_1 \cup H_2) $ where $$ H_1 = \{(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4) | x_1=x_2=0 \} , H_2 = \{(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4) | x_3=x_4=0 \} $$ are two dimensional subspaces. This space clearly deformation retracts to $ S^3 $ minus two copies of $ S^1 $, which are given by the equations $ C_1:x_3^2 + x_4^2 = 1 $ and $ C_2:x_1^2 + x_2^2 = 1 $. Now use stereographic projection from the north pole $ (0,0,0,1) $ to see that $ C_2 $ goes to the same circle in $ \mathbb{R}^3 $ while $ C_1 $ maps to the $ z$-axis of $ \mathbb{R}^3 $. So finally, you need to compute the fundamental group of $ \mathbb{R}^3 \setminus (\{ x^2 + y^2 = 1 \} \cup \{ (0,0,z) | z \in \mathbb{R} \}) $. This space deformation retracts to a torus, whose fundamental group is $ \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} $.

Comment: Why do you take two dimensional subspaces? Here the hyperplanes have dimension one less than the dimension of $\Bbb R^4$ and hence their dimension are $3$. Am I right?

Comment: No. What is the dimension of the subspace $ H_1 $? It is $ 2 $, the $ x_3, x_4 $ are free variables. As for why do I take two dimensional subspaces, isn't that is what's asked in your problem? A point $ \{ z_1, z_2 \} \in \mathbb{C}^2 $ where $ z_1 =0 $ is given by a point in $ H_1 $ in $ \mathbb{R}^4 $.

Comment: How do I visualise the stereographic projection in $4$-dimension?

Comment: The same way as you do in three (or two) dimensions. The formulae are identical.

Comment: I found that $C_1$ maps to the $z$-axis under the formula $(x,y,z)= \left (\frac {x_1} {1-x_4} , \frac {x_2} {1-x_4} , \frac {x_3} {1-x_4} \right)$ by substituting $x_1 = x_2 = 0$ and $C_2$ maps to a circle $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ by substituting $x_3=x_4=0$. Am I right now?

Comment: Why do you take $z$-axis by the formula $z=0$? $z=0$ actually represents the $xy$-plane not the $z$-axis. $z$-axis is represented by the formula $x=0,y=0$.

Comment: Yes, your formula is correct and indeed, it is the formula for the stereographic projection map. The z-axis is my mistake, thank you for pointing it out. Will be edited.

Comment: But can you clarify why $\Bbb R^3$ without a circle and $z$-axis is a deformation retract of a torus?

Comment: The entire space is obtained by revolving about the z-axis a 'slice' which is a plane minus a point. Does that help?